# Problem with system of equations $(x,y,z)$

Tags: systems-of-equations

System of equations:
$$\begin{cases}\frac{x}{yz}+\frac{y}{zx}+\frac{z}{xy}=\frac{3}{xyz}\\xy+yz+zx=3\end{cases}$$
Solution:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{x}{yz}+\frac{y}{zx}+\frac{z}{xy}=\frac{3}{xyz}\\xy+yz+zx=3\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=3\\xy+yz+zx=3\end{cases}$$

$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=xy+yz+zx$

$(x+y+z)^{2}-2(xy+yz+zx)=xy+yz+zx$

$(x+y+z)^{2}-2*3=3$

$(x+y+z)^{2}=9$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=?$$

Alternatively, $$x^2-x(y+z)+y^2+z^2-yz=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

But $$(y+z)^2-4(y^2+z^2-yz)=-3(y-z)^2\le0$$

Answer (score 0):

By the calculations you have made, your system is actually eqivalent to $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=3\\(x+y+z)^2=9\end{cases}$$Which is, at the same time, equivalent to the systems $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=3\\x+y+z=3\end{cases} \quad \begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=3\\x+y+z=-3\end{cases}$$But you can check using the distance formula between a point and a plane (or in many other ways) that the planes $x+y+z=3$ and $x+y+z=-3$ are both tangent to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$, so the only solutions are $x=y=z=\pm1$

Answer (score 0):

For the system $\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=3\\x+y+z=3\end{cases}\quad$ just offset the variables $\begin{cases}x=1+X\\y=1+Y\\z=1+Z\end{cases}$

Then you get $\begin{cases}3+X+Y+Z=3\\3+2X+2Y+2Z+X^2+Y^2+Z^2=3\end{cases}\implies X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$

Which in the real domain has only the $(0,0,0)$ solution.

For $x+y+z=-3$ proceed similarly with $x=X-1,y=Y-1,z=Z-1$.